# What should I be logging in my apps

Tags: logging, log4net

I am a Junior developer and I have been tasked with installing Log4Net in my app and getting it working. That part is done. My question is What should I be loggining.

It seems very broad and I am mainly looking for an article/blog post/book that really says what to log or why you log specific events. I realize this could be very opinion laden but when I am googling around for an answer everyone says you should do it not why/what specifically you should log.

Comment: It depends...on the audience/purpose of the log. An EDP-auditor needs different info then the maintenance/support team. You better ask them...logging also needs specs, just like the rest of the application.

Comment: I agree with that the problem is none of our apps currently have logging in them. I am looking for some sort of guideline to move us toward a future in logging and doing so with best practices in mind

Comment: In that case, do a step-by-step approach, inspired by http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging//guide.html#Best_Practices_General

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently given a similar task and felt the same way. I had to add logging to an installer. I logged the date and time the install was started, when it was completed and if it was completed successfully. I also log exceptions so I know where the install failed if it does and why.